# What real-life artist draws Sagiri's art in the anime?

Tags: eromanga-sensei

In *Eromanga-sensei*, Sagiri draws various pieces of (mostly-lewd) art in her guise as "Eromanga-sensei". For example, this one from episode 12:

[image: ep12 01:11]

Who is the real-life artist who draws the pictures that are portrayed as Sagiri's art in the anime?

There's a very consistent style to all of them, so I'm thinking it's just one person, but it doesn't look like Kanzaki Hiro's work (he's the character designer / artist for the *Eromanga-sensei* light novel).

Comment: self-help tip: try finding a clean screencap of one of these arts and reverse-image-search it :p

Comment: This _is_ a "clean" screencap - in-show, Sagiri is streaming her art over "Niyaniya" (fake Niconico) and people are commenting on it. In any case, one can hardly expect reverse-image-searching to be any more useful here than it would be for answering "who animated this scene" or "who drew the backgrounds in this scene".

Comment: ok then, [you could try applying the multi-shot cleanup technique used to remove tourists from a shot where lots of things are obscuring the object in different spots at different times](https://i.imgur.com/4EUrk2g.jpg)

Answer (score 5):

Ah, it's [Tiv](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiv), who tweeted about this [here](https://twitter.com/tiv_/status/850743251493453824):

> アニメ「エロマンガ先生」、紗霧ちゃんのお仕事に協力させていただいてます。これからもしばらくよろしくお願いします！#エロマンガ先生
>
> I'll be helping with Sagiri's work on the anime 'Eromanga-sensei'. [usual Japanese pleasantries] #EromangaSensei

Tiv is probably better known for being the artist for the *Masamune-kun no Revenge* LNs/manga; the resemblance of that and her other art to Sagiri's art is unmistakable (see e.g. [her portfolio website "Planova"](http://planova.net/)).